# Codeigniter 2.1 - insert HTML page into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to create mini CMS, where user can create new page and then that page become part of menu. Is it smart to insert full pages into database or there is better way to do so? Also I am having a bit of the problem with **a tag** when I am inserting. 
Code for now:

For inserting page into db:

```
public function strana_insert()
    {
        $this->admin_login_check();
        $clear = $this->str->clean_request();

        $char  = array('\n', '\n');
        $strana  = str_replace($char, '<br>', $clear['opis']);
        $kljucna_rec = str_replace( ' ', '_', mb_convert_case($clear['naziv'], MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8") );
            $data = array(
            'naziv'           => $clear['naziv'],
            'strana'          => htmlspecialchars($strana, ENT_QUOTES , "UTF-8"),
            'kljucna_rec'     => $kljucna_rec,
            'datum_kreiranja' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        );
        $this->str->save($data);
        $this->save_routes();
        redirect('admin');
    }
```

Code for clean_request function:

```
public function clean_request()
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) :
            $clean[$key]=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($value));
        endforeach;

        return $clean;
    }
```

When I insert page with **a tag** I get following result:

```
<a href=\"http://www.example.com\" class=\"link_name\">www.example.com</a>
```

After updating page everything between **\ ** is deleted. What is going on here?

Comment: what is your db field? varchar or text?

Comment: Don't use mysql_real_escape_string, use the framework's DB class with bindings (or Active Record). The backslashes could be the magic_quotes setting on your server; turn them off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use Codeigniter's active class to insert this** OR use the following method.

before inserting HTML data to database do this :

```
$html_for_db = addslashes($html_content);
```

and insert `$html_for_db` to database.

While displaying this content,

```
echo stripcslashes($data_from_db);
```

**stripcslashes() - Un-quote string quoted with addcslashes**

More info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Why! why using addslashes? If you want to escape a string, it's wrong, especially since the framework provides better ways to do that natively. If you want to escape html, addslashes makes no sense

Comment: @DamienPirsy, Thanks for your valuable information let me search and edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

it's because of escape function!! 
htmlspecialchar change your code to just a simple string!!

if you'd like to save as html you should save the code without escaping!

BTW, This isn't an smart way to create a static pages, You may like to create a layout and simply let users put content in it ;)

Comment: This is the way I am doing it. Layout for the page is already set, but there is a need for few tweaks (class here and there, bold text and so on).

Comment: btw , codeigniter escape your code automatically for having safer query; resource : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: simply , do not escape the content .

Comment: could you give me a shot about your database field!!?

Comment: Type of the field is longtext.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store html in your DB I recommend using htmlpurifier to clean up your html code and also strip out unwanted html tags.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

There is also a helper which makes using htmlpurifier within CodeIgniter really easy: https://github.com/refringe/codeigniter-htmlpurifier

After you cleaned your input string with htmlpurifier you should use Codeigniters Active Record class to insert your data (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html). This way the framework will do the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent two types of attacks here: SQL injection and cross-side scripting. You considered both and used `htmlspecialchars()` against XSS and `mysql_real_escape_string()` against SQL injection.

But you used them in the wrong order. You first have to use htmlspecialchars, because that's the thing you want to store/output. To put it savely into the database you have to wrap it into its mysql_real_escape_string-ized presentation before storing it or use parameter binding instead.